# Aggregate Family Rate Limits on Juniper EX

Tags: juniper, policing, juniper-ex

Trying to figure out how to perform rate limits on Juniper EX for both inet and inet6 families.  Ideally I'd like a packet rate limiter to be applied before the ip type is ever looked at.  Basically, I don't care whether the traffic is V6, V4, or MPLS, I want to rate limit all packets incoming to the interface.

To note, the addresses for each family are applied directly to the interface.  I can't see a way to actually make this work.

The work around I've found is to convert the interface to layer-2, stick it in a vlan, create an RVI and apply all the addressing to the that.  Then make the interface 'family ethernet-switching' and apply a policer there.  That seems like a lot of work around to get something which, to me, should be pretty straightforward.

EX4550 running 12.3R2.5

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 8):

You are looking for the "Logical Interface (Aggregate) Policer":

http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/junos11.4/topics/concept/policer-logical-interface-aggregate-overview.html

Unfortunately they are only available on EX9200 (which is a castrated MX) if the information on the EX feature page is correct:

http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/release-independent/junos/topics/concept/ex-series-software-features-overview.html#routing-policy-packet-filtering-features-by-platform-table